# flex 4.6 mobile application: can I make .exe from it?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4, flex4.5, flex4.6

I am developping a mobile application with Flex4.6.
I could create an output for ipad and android.

I could also create an AIR application.

Is that possible to create an .EXE for PC from this AIR ?

regards

Comment: When you install an AIR application you get a folder with an exe in it (and all other files). If this is not the case, you could place your code in a air-project , build it and install it to get the exe

Comment: I don't get .exe and I just want to create a new AIR project to avoid fremgentation of versions.

Answer (score 3):

> Is that possible to create an .EXE for PC from this AIR ?

Yes, you can create an AIR project that builds an .exe on Windows.  To do this, when you generate a release build, you have to do so using the "captive runtime" feature.

From within Flash Builder, you cannot create a single project that will target mobile (AKA iOS and Android) and Desktops (Mac and PC).  If that is your purpose, then you should consider moving as much code as possibly into a library project; and then sharing that library project between a Flex Project (aimed at the Desktop) and a Flex Mobile Project (aimed at iOS and Android).

Answer (score 1):

Its best to create a library project with all your common base code, (i.e. almost everything) then create 2 other projects, one for mobile, one for desktop which reference the library project.

In the desktop one you will also need to import the mobile skin references into the project if you want to have exactly the same look and feel.

I've just done this myself.  I have an iPad version and a Desktop version but they both use the same library and the mobile skins.

You can also then in the desktop and mobile projects setup separate launch mxmls and include different css style sheets to cater for any other differences you may want to have.